# Restrict access to Chatter Posts based on an attribute of the current user

Tags: lightning-aura-components, chatter, chatter-feed

We have 2 brands of one Parent company, they currently share certain Accounts in a single Org.

We need to restrict access to the Chatter posts so that each brand can only see the posts made by other users within the same brand related to that account.

It doesn't look like i can use the force:Chatter components to achieve this, they will simply show everything related to the Account.

Any other ideas? Completely rebuilding the Chatter UI from scratch isnt particularly appealing at the moment...

Comment: Is this for internal Chatter or for a Community Chatter? In either case, what is your sharing on your Accounts. Also, do you have a Product Based Hierarchy  or a Functional Based one? It seems you need to differentiate your records and access by Brand.

Comment: Internal Chatter. Unfortunately, theyre determined to have some shared accounts between brands but they dont want a shared chatter feed...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you followed where I was heading with my question in comments. If the products associated between the two Brands had different RecordTypes then only those who have that RecordType associated with their profile will be able to view posts related to them.

This would require that any discussions around the Account have a reference to a product from one of the Brands and not to products from both Brands. I hope this is clear to you. To implement this, you'd need to create 2 record types, one for each brand and associate products for those brands with each record type. You'd also want to implement a Sales Process for each brand (doesn't matter if they're the same, you'd still want one defined for each Brand).

Each profile will then need to have a default record type assigned to it. Check the docs for more on how record types work. You can use permission sets, but they do not provide for different page layouts that you might use for the record types. If you use the same one, it wouldn't matter, but I'd expect that with different branding you'd be using different ones anyway.